# CakePHP3 "Creative" routing with Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.4. I'm developing a plugin, let's call it `MyPlugin`.

MyPlugin has 2 route prefixes, let's call one `/books` and the other one `/authors`. Each one of those has set of controllers associated with the route.

In an application, I want to be able to declare in the routes file that the prefix `/admin/books` point to the books route in the plugin, and the `/authors` to point to `/authors`. How should I go about doing that?

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->prefix('admin/books', ['plugin' => 'MyPlugin'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks();
    });

    $routes->prefix('authors', ['plugin' => 'MyPlugin'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks();
    });
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});

Router::plugin(
    'MyPlugin',
    ['path' => '/'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->prefix('/books', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
          // controller actions...
        });

        $routes->prefix('/authors', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
          //controller actions...
        });
    }
);
```

Edit in response to @ndm:

The problem I'm facing, is that the plugin needs to be able to to have certain controllers control the '/' for SEO purposes without the plugin prefix, but needs to have some routes protected because they are admin routes.

Comment: You're question reads a little **[xy-ish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/227568)**, ie it's more about your attempted solution, rather than about the actual problem that you're trying to solve. It would probably help if you'd exlpain _why_ you want to create custom routes instead of making use of the ones that the plugin provides.

Comment: That being said, it sounds as if you want to create route "aliases" - that's not possible with the built-in routing, unless maybe the plugin would fully rely on named routes, and wouldn't attempt to overwrite them. Also be aware that prefixes have a special meaning, they connect to controllers in subnamespaces!